# Ethereum Name Service (ENS). How do you discern the registrant/owner of an expired name?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, ens

I'm a bit stumped on this one.

The [Base Registrar Implementation](https://etherscan.io/address/0x57f1887a8bf19b14fc0df6fd9b2acc9af147ea85#code) contract of the Ethereum Name Service (ENS) extends from the ERC721 token standard.

It implements/overrides the `ownerOf` method as follows:

```
/**
 * @dev Gets the owner of the specified token ID. Names become unowned
 *      when their registration expires.
 * @param tokenId uint256 ID of the token to query the owner of
 * @return address currently marked as the owner of the given token ID
 */
function ownerOf(uint256 tokenId) public view returns (address) {
    require(expiries[tokenId] > now);
    return super.ownerOf(tokenId);
}
```

As such an expired domain name that is in the 90 day grace period will throw.

I want to get what we might semantically call the `previous` registrant address. How can one achieve this? Is there a way to implement a method in my own Solidity contract that calls through directly to the parent `super` implementation of `ownerOf` from the ERC721 contract?

Comment: you need to scan all ENS events, there are 2 of them "NewOwner" and "OwnerChanged" , these events report the ownership